# In Windows command line, list all directories without parent path

Tags: batch-file

I need a way to capture all of the directories, (and sub-directories), but without the parent directory.

For example:

```
C:\Users\Joe> DIR *.* /b /ad /s
C:\Users\Joe\AppData
C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Microsoft
...
```

I need the listing without `C:\Users\Joe` at the beginning.

*This will be going into a batch file with a wide audience so I would prefer not to use any 3rd party tools.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `For` loop, you could `Echo` the files minus the current directory.

With delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L') Do (Set "file=%%A"
    Echo=!file:%__CD__%=!)
Pause
```

Without delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L') Do (Set "file=%%A"
    Call Echo=%%file:%__CD__%=%%)
Pause
```

With delayed expansion and with the leading backslash:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L') Do (Set "file=%%A"
    Echo=!file:%CD%=!)
Pause
```

Without delayed expansion and with the leading backslash:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L') Do (Set "file=%%A"
    Call Echo=%%file:%CD%=%%)
Pause
```

With delayed expansion as a relative path:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L') Do (Set "file=%%A"
    Echo=.!file:%CD%=!)
Pause
```

Without delayed expansion as a relative path:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-L') Do (Set "file=%%A"
    Call Echo=.%%file:%CD%=%%)
Pause
```